# how to detect SQL duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and trying to detect duplicate values with several keys. But there are too many graph to join.

```
ID  Price  category  discount  name
1    5       A         5%      apple
2    5       A         5%      pear
3    6       B         6%      melon
4    2       B         7%      pencil
```

I want to get the results (with different IDs and names, but Price, category and discount duplicate)like

```
ID  Price  category  discount  name
1    5       A         5%      apple
2    5       A         5%      pear
```

they are all in different database,[ID_Db],[Des],[CAT],[NA]
I use:

```
SELECT 
ID.[ID] AS 'ID',
Des.[Price] AS 'price',
Des.[discount] AS 'discount',
category.[category] AS 'category',
name.[name] AS 'name'


FROM
[ID_Db] ID 
LEFT JOIN [Des] Des
ON ID.[ID]=Des.[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [CAT] category
ON category.[ID]=Des.[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [NA] name
ON category.[ID]=name.[ID] 

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT category.[category],Des.[discount],Des.[Price]
    FROM [ID_Db] ID ,
         LEFT JOIN [Des] Des,
         ON ID.[ID]=Des.[ID], 
         LEFT JOIN [category] category,
         ON category.[ID]=Des.[ID] 
    GROUP BY category.[category],Des.[discount],Des.[Price]
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))OS
ON ID.ID= OS.[ID]
```

I got an error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.
I simply with the subquery as

```
SELECT category.[category],Des.[discount],Des.[Price]
FROM [ID_Db] ID ,
     LEFT JOIN [Des] Des,
     ON ID.[ID]=Des.[ID], 
     LEFT JOIN [category] category,
     ON category.[ID]=Des.[ID] 
GROUP BY category.[category],Des.[discount],Des.[Price]
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))OS
ORDER BY category desC
```

But the results are not rows with duplicate values.

Could someone please help with that? Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232408/discussion-on-question-by-joyce-how-to-detect-sql-duplicate-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you just want window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID.[ID], Des.[Price], Des.[discount], category.[category]
    name.[name],
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category.[category], Des.[discount],Des.[Price]) as cnt
      FROM [ID_Db] ID LEFT JOIN
           [Des] Des
           ON ID.[ID] = Des.[ID] LEFT JOIN
           [CAT] category
           ON category.[ID] = Des.[ID] LEFT JOIN
           [NA] name
           ON category.[ID] = name.[ID] 
     ) x
WHERE cnt > 1;
```